# Twython 401 Error for Raspberry Pi Tweetbot

Tags: twitter, raspberry-pi, twython

In order to tweet both a photo (taken from the picamera) and a status update, I ran the following code on my raspberry pi:

```
!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from twython import Twython
import os

import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.start()
image = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(image,'webcam.jpg')

CONSUMER_KEY = 'X'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'X'
ACCESS_KEY = 'X'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'X'

photo = open('webcam.jpg','rb')
api = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)
api.update_status_with_media(media=photo, status='Hello There!')
```

With correctly filled in access and token keys I received the following error:

```
'Twitter API returned a 401 (unauthorised), Timestamp out of bounds'
```

After configuring both my raspberry pi and Twitter account to the same timezone, the problem persisted.

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: In the code you assigned 'X' to the CONSUMER and ACCESS KEY and SECRET. I assume that's because you want to hide your values from the public. If the 'X' also occur in your private copy of the script, then that could be the problem.  Twitter simply moans that you are not authorized. Do you have requested an API key from Twitter?

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I did a quick regeneration of the API Keys and that seemed to fix the 400 error though now when run it receives the following message: 'Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorised). Timestamp out of bounds'. Any ideas? Thanks Again

Comment: To me it seems to be the same error message ???

Comment: "It means that your server time is off by more than 30 seconds (actual time not including time-zone differences). Look at the response header to see what Twitter's time is."

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/223):

> "It means that your server time is off by more than 30 seconds (actual
>   time not including time-zone differences). Look at the response header
>   to see what Twitter's time is."

So, you have to set the time of your server to match the Twitter time. Inspect the header of a Twitter response, look up the time in the `Date` field and compare it with your raspberry pi os time (and change this accordingly).